# I'm trying to load the Sanctions XML list to a sql table but I'm getting nulls

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

SQL:

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn  
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\echo\20220617.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://eu.europa.ec/fpi/fsd/export')

SELECT 
    firstName = resource.value('(../../nameAlias/firstName)[1]', 'varchar(30)')--,
    --lastName = resource.value('(../../nameAlias/lastName)[1]', 'varchar(30)')--,
    --wholeName = resource.value('(../../nameAlias/wholeName)[1]', 'varchar(30)')--,
FROM
    @XmlFile.nodes('//export/sanctionEntity/remark/regulation/subjecttype/nameAlias/nameAlias/nameAlias/citizenship') AS XTbl1(resource)
```

SAMPLE XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<export xmlns="http://eu.europa.ec/fpi/fsd/export" generationDate="2022-06-17T10:52:41.812+02:00" globalFileId="141482">
    <sanctionEntity designationDetails="" unitedNationId="" euReferenceNumber="EU.27.28" logicalId="13">
        <remark>UNSC RESOLUTION 1483</remark>
        <regulation regulationType="regulation" organisationType="commission" publicationDate="2003-07-08" entryIntoForceDate="2003-07-07" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" programme="IRQ" logicalId="348">
            <publicationUrl>http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF</publicationUrl>
        </regulation>
        <subjectType code="person" classificationCode="P"/>
        <nameAlias firstName="Saddam" middleName="" lastName="Hussein Al-Tikriti" wholeName="Saddam Hussein Al-Tikriti" function="" gender="M" title="" nameLanguage="" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="17">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </nameAlias>
        <nameAlias firstName="" middleName="" lastName="" wholeName="Abu Ali" function="" title="" nameLanguage="" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="19">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </nameAlias>
        <nameAlias firstName="" middleName="" lastName="" wholeName="Abou Ali" function="" title="" nameLanguage="FR" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="380">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </nameAlias>
        <citizenship region="" countryIso2Code="IQ" countryDescription="IRAQ" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="1">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </citizenship>
        <birthdate circa="false" calendarType="GREGORIAN" city="al-Awja, near Tikrit" zipCode="" birthdate="1937-04-28" dayOfMonth="28" monthOfYear="4" year="1937" region="" place="" countryIso2Code="IQ" countryDescription="IRAQ" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="14">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </birthdate>
    </sanctionEntity>
    <sanctionEntity designationDetails="" unitedNationId="" euReferenceNumber="EU.39.56" logicalId="20">
        <remark>Saddam's second son</remark>
        <regulation regulationType="regulation" organisationType="commission" publicationDate="2003-07-08" entryIntoForceDate="2003-07-07" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" programme="IRQ" logicalId="348">
            <publicationUrl>http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF</publicationUrl>
        </regulation>
        <subjectType code="person" classificationCode="P"/>
        <nameAlias firstName="Qoussaï" middleName="Saddam" lastName="Hussein Al-Tikriti" wholeName="Qoussaï Saddam Hussein Al-Tikriti" function="" title="" nameLanguage="FR" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="381">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </nameAlias>
        <nameAlias firstName="Qusay" middleName="Saddam" lastName="Hussein Al-Tikriti" wholeName="Qusay Saddam Hussein Al-Tikriti" function="Oversaw Special Republican Guard, Special Security Organisation, and Republican Guard" gender="M" title="" nameLanguage="" strong="true" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="26">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </nameAlias>
        <citizenship region="" countryIso2Code="IQ" countryDescription="IRAQ" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="2">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </citizenship>
        <birthdate circa="false" calendarType="GREGORIAN" city="Baghdad" zipCode="" year="1965" region="" place="" countryIso2Code="00" countryDescription="UNKNOWN" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="19">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </birthdate>
        <birthdate circa="false" calendarType="GREGORIAN" city="Baghdad" zipCode="" year="1966" region="" place="" countryIso2Code="00" countryDescription="UNKNOWN" regulationLanguage="en" logicalId="20">
            <regulationSummary regulationType="regulation" publicationDate="2003-07-08" numberTitle="1210/2003 (OJ L169)" publicationUrl="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:169:0006:0023:EN:PDF"/>
        </birthdate>
    </sanctionEntity>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Is that url still working? http://eu.europa.ec/fpi/fsd/export

Answer (score 2):

First of all - you need to change your XPath for the `.nodes()` - see my sample below.

And then - the first and last name are **attributes** on XML nodes - you need to select those like this (`@firstname` on the proper node):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://eu.europa.ec/fpi/fsd/export')
SELECT 
    firstName = resource.value('(@firstName)', 'varchar(30)'),
    lastName = resource.value('(@lastName)', 'varchar(30)')
FROM
    @XmlFile.nodes('/export/sanctionEntity/nameAlias') AS XTbl1(resource)
```